# Best method of calculating the integral of a function in PHP?

Tags: php, normal-distribution, integral

I am making a normal distribution calculator in PHP, but I can't figure out how to calculate the integral of a function using PHP. 
I've searched the web and stackoverflow, but I can't find anything on the topic. 
The closest I've come is via php.net where someone referrers to the [Composite Simpson's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule) to get an approximation, but I would like to get a precise result and not just an approximation.

Is there any commonly know way to achieve my goal, that I am missing, and if there are several which would be the best for calculating normal distribution?

Comment: where whould you store that "precise" result? in a float?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral of the normal distribution is known as the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) (often abbreviated as `erf`). There doesn't appear to be any native implementation in PHP, but the Wikipedia page has several good approximations under "[Approximation with elementary functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Approximation_with_elementary_functions)".

Answer (score 0):

Except in certain trivial cases, it's not possible to precisely integrate the probability density function of the normal distribution.